# class of compact support functions is dense in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I came across the following while looking at some notes from a course about Sobolev spaces.

The exercise is to prove the density of compactly supported functions in the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n).$ I am aware of a proof of this fact using mollifiers and cut-off functions. For some reason I am stuck to this. I suppose it is a straightforward application of the definition of convergence in Sobolev spaces combined with a pointwise estimate for the derivatives, arising when applying the Leibniz rule.

> Let $\phi \in C^\infty (\mathbb R)$ such that
>
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \phi(t)=0,  & \text{if} \hspace{0.05in} t\leq -1 \\
> %
> 0 \leq \phi(t) \leq 1, & \text{if} \hspace{0.05in} -1 \leq t \leq 0 \\
> %
> \phi(t)=1 & \text{if} \hspace{0.05in}  t \geq 0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> For $m>0$ define the function $ \displaystyle \phi_m(t)= \phi(m+t) \phi(m-t)$ and for $ x \in \mathbb R^n$ define $ \psi_m(x)= \phi_m(x_1) \cdots \phi_m(x_n).$
>
> Given a function $ u \in W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n) ,$ prove that $ \psi_m u \to u $ (as $ m \to \infty$ ) in the sobolev space $W^{m,p}(\mathbb R^n).$
>
> Conclude that the functions with compact support are dense in $W^{m,p}(\mathbb R^n).$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the product $\psi_m u $ is necessarily smooth? We probably need a convolution somewhere

Comment: @GaC: Thank you for your comment. Now, i think the exercise is stated correctly. I The thing is that I was also expecting a convolution. That's the ''typical'' approach I had in mind and the one that is used in my references. That's why i decided to post it here.